# Bose-Einstein condensate interference why same phase

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

I understand that a quantum particle/wave free of potential has a square of the wave function 1 everywhere and a wave function $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$  and as consequence of that in Bose-Einstein condensate the wave functions spread over time so that particles are "less localized" but I don't know ***why the phase of most of those bosons is almost the same***. Maybe because those bosons are freed of the potential at the same time?

Comment: "Why the phase of most of those bosons is almost the same..." because it's a "condensate" (i.e. macroscopic occupation of the same single-particle state).